# Proving $f^{-1}$ is concave.

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

Let $f:(a,b)\to \mathbb R$ be an invertible, non-decreasing convex function. Prove $f^{-1}$ is concave. There are all these theorems and rules but I can't make it there... Would appreciate your help.

Comment: What ways do you know to show that a function is concave?

Comment: There are several definitions of convexity. The most general one does not use derivatives, while definitions in elementary calculus usually do. Which one is in use here? Oh, and regardless of which definition, the prototypical example is the exponential function and its inverse, the logarithm. It may help to make some drawings involving those.

Comment: If the chord between any two points on the function's is above the function in the limits that are between the $x$ coordinates...

Comment: There might be other ways I guess

Comment: @Meitar: It's important to work from the definitions you are given.  But that's a good one.  What is the relationship between the graph of $f$ and $f^{-1}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x,x'\in(a,b)$ and $y=f(x),y'=f(x')$ and $\lambda\in[0,1]$ then since $f$ is non decreasing then $f^{-1}$ is non-decreasing so the desired result is based on the definition of the convexity:

$$f(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)x')\le \lambda f(x)+(1-\lambda)f(x')\iff \lambda x+(1-\lambda)x'\le f^{-1}(\lambda f(x)+(1-\lambda)f(y)\\\iff \lambda f^{-1}(y)+(1-\lambda)f^{-1}(y')\le f^{-1}(\lambda y+(1-\lambda)y')$$

Comment: Thank you very much.
Apparently, that was the right way to look at it...

Answer (score 3):

Graph of $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are symmetric about $y=x$, so if $f$ is non decreasing convex fnction then $f^{-1}$ must be concave.

Comment: But $f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$...

Comment: @Lehs: Neeraj's approach is sound, just a little terse.

Comment: here $f:(a,b)\to \Bbb{R}$

Comment: Yes, I'm wrong!

Answer (score 2):

If $f$ is non-decreasing and invertible, so is $f^{-1}$.

Since $f$ is convex, we have, for $\lambda \in [0,1]$,
$f(\lambda x + (1-\lambda )y) \le \lambda f(x) + (1-\lambda) f(y)$. Applying
$f^{-1}$ gives
$\lambda x + (1-\lambda )y) \le f^{-1}(\lambda f(x) + (1-\lambda) f(y))$.

Now suppose $x=f^{-1}(s), y=f^{-1}(t)$, then this gives
the desired result.

**Alternative**: Here is a more geometric approach (inspired by Neeraj's answer):

Again, this hinges on the fact that if $f$ is non-decreasing, then so
is $f^{-1}$.

Note that $(x,y) \in \operatorname{epi} f$  **iff** $y \ge f(x)$ **iff**
$f^{-1}(y) \ge x$ **iff** $-x \ge -f^{-1}(y)$ **iff** $(y,-x) \in \operatorname{epi} (-f^{-1})$.

Since $f$ is convex and the transformation $\phi(x,y) = (y,-x)$ is linear, we see that $\operatorname{epi} (-f^{-1}) = \phi (\operatorname{epi} f)$ and so
it is convex and hence $-f^{-1}$ is convex. Taking account of the minus sign, we see that $f^{-1}$ is concave.

Comment: Glad to be of help. I added a more geometric answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proof that is probably not the most useful for the OP and requires extra assumptions.  But it's a neat chain rule application.

Suppose additionally that $f$ is twice-differentiable.  Since the graph of $f$ is convex, we have $f''(x) > 0$ for all $x$ within in the domain of $f$.  Since $f$ is non-decreasing, $f'(x) > 0$ for all $x$ too.

(I think the convexity and monotonicity assumptions together rule out $f'(x) = 0$. The canonical counterexample $f(x) = x^3$ doesn't satisfy the concavity assumption.  In case I am wrong, we can go ahead and assume $f'(x) > 0$ for all $x$.)

The inverse function theorem tells us that for all $y$ in the range of $f$,
$$
(f^{-1})'(y) = \frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(y))}
$$
Take another derivative, and apply the chain rule:
\begin{align*}
    (f^{-1})''(y) &= \frac{-1}{(f'(f^{-1}(y)))^2} \cdot f''(f^{-1}(y)) \cdot (f^{-1})'(y) \\
&= \frac{-1}{(f'(f^{-1}(y)))^2} \cdot f''(f^{-1}(y)) \cdot \frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(y))} \\
&= \frac{- f''(f^{-1}(y))}{(f'(f^{-1}(y)))^3}
\end{align*}
Since $f'$ and $f''$ are positive, we have $(f^{-1})''(y) < 0$.  So the graph of $f^{-1}$ is concave.